# Mend scratch in laminate flooring

Tags: laminate-floor, scratches

While moving, I scratched the vinyl flooring. It is a "wood" laminate flooring, where the planks support material with a wood print veneer (as mentioned in [Can/Should I seal laminate "wood" flooring?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49210/can-should-i-seal-laminate-wood-flooring/51102)). As far as I have been told the flooring is design "Life 710670003" by https://www.project-floors.com.

The scratch is running perpendicular to the grain. It measures about 1 metre in length and about 1.5 millimetres in with. I have no idea how to measure the exact depth. Apart from a few millimetres, the veneer is not ripped apart, only pushed into the base material. [image: scratched "wood" laminate floor]
The landlord is not amused since the scratch is located in the middle of the room, it is well visible and it can be felt when walked on. I want to try to fix the floor visually and structurally as much as possible. At minimum, I would like to level it out to avoid dirt accumulation.

Ideally, one would replace the affected planks. However, there are no spares available. As it turned out, this flooring has been discontinued altogether. Hence I cannot purchase replacements either. Divot replacements (like discussed in 
[Divot repair in laminate flooring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/136073/divot-repair-in-laminate-flooring)) are out of the question, too.

The producer Project Floors does not provide the technical details of this particular flooring (due to discontinuation, probably). For this reason, I do not know with what materials I am dealing with exactly.

Most flooring patching methods are geared towards flat-colour PVC and are not applicable to my case. There are repair methods involving fillers and/or hard wax, but they seem to apply exclusively to hardwood flooring.

Is there anything I can try or is this 'bout a scratch, but ultimately a lost cause?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is going to make it disappear 100%, but with a little artistic talent you can hide it pretty good.

You're looking for a [Laminate touch-up kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00UD620N6) (or the [cheap version](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075ZZXB8K)). Essentially you fill the crack with hard wax, and then paint it to match the 'texture'. The better your knack for colors, the better the result.

Comment: A good tip. I was under the impression, the hard wax would only bond well with real wood surfaces. The linked kit's description at least claims otherwise. It seems to be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Durham's wood putty to just about all surface scratches in soft wood trim and door frames don't know how it would handle traffic but I've stained it to match almost anything problem with vinyl laminate flooring is how fragile it is once the clear coating is removed it will swell and crumble if exposed to moisture. I have used a few different cabinet repairing kits that we're for laminate particle wood cabinets that had a pretty cool crayon like touch up that wouldnt rub off under fingers, but again feet are heavier. Honestly I don't think anything will ever fix it short of replacement but gently scrape the edges sand it, use a wood filler and wax or clear coat it and it won't be exposed like it is now ...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to read your answer; would you edit it a bit to add a few more sentences, and even a paragraph or two? Thanks.