# How to fix scratch on laminate hardwood

Tags: repair, laminate-floor

[image]

How can I fix this deep scratch

Comment: Fixing it like new is not possible without replacing board.  The surface is too damaged.  Can use a coloured filler to kind of cover it, but laminate is very thin and you have gone though it to base wood.

Comment: Can see this link for some ideas.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/147895/mend-scratch-in-laminate-flooring?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mend scratch in laminate flooring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/147895/mend-scratch-in-laminate-flooring)

Comment: Laminate doesn't generally get fixed, it gets replaced. Luckily it's damaged parallel with the grain. You *could* get some stain which matches the floor, try to apply it with something thin like a toothpick, and brush off any excess. Just have to be careful not to stain the surrounding undamaged floor. Good luck!